# In MySQL, how can I use the autoincrement value in another column at the time of the INSERT?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, sql-insert

I am looking to have the automagically set autoincrement included in another column during the insert.  For example in a table where ID is the autoincrement and Name is the other column, I'd like to do something like

```
`INSERT INTO Names (Name) VALUES (CONCAT("I am number ",ID));`
```

Currently, I do the INSERT without Name, then I have to immediately after do an UPDATE using $mysqli->insert_id.

I don't want to query the table in advance because, as small a time as it may be, another record could get inserted between getting the next autoincrement value and the insertion.  A trigger could work, but it seems like overkill.  I just want to know if I can reference the autoincrement within the insertion.

Many thanks!

Comment: I haven't tried, but does it not work if you just refer to the id-field by name in your INSERT query?

Comment: have you tried using `TRIGGER`?

Comment: JW, I've read about how to do it with `TRIGGER` and it seems a little too "far away from the INSERT".  If I can't have it be in the INSERT, I'll keep the `UPDATE`.
Andrew, I had assumed it would be ambiguous as to whether it would take the value before or after the autoincrement, so I tried it out just now.  Maybe I assumed wrong.  I got "I am number 0". The to setting of the autoincrement data didn't take place. Even if it did, I'd still be concerned it might work differently on different SQLs.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not as easy as it seems. In a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger, the autoincrement value hasn't been generated yet (`NEW.autoinc_column` is `0`), and in an `AFTER INSERT` trigger, it is not possible anymore to change the values to be inserted.

With MyISAM tables, you could check the table definition for the next `AUTO_INCREMENT` value:

```
DELIMITER //    

    CREATE TRIGGER inserName BEFORE INSERT ON name FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        DECLARE next_ai INT;
        SELECT auto_increment INTO next_ai
          FROM information_schema.tables
          WHERE table_schema = DATABASE() AND table_name = 'name';
        SET NEW.name = CONCAT("I am number ", next_ai);
    END //

DELIMITER ;
```

I believe this could work too with InnoDB tables if `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 0` (not the case by default), but I am not sure (because of possible concurrency issues).

But if the value to concat is always the same, you probably had better using a view such as:

```
CREATE VIEW names_v AS SELECT id, CONCAT("I am number ", id) AS name FROM names;
```

Comment: YaK, thanks for the thoughtful reply.  I'm not looking to use a `TRIGGER` because it seemed to be as complicated as you describe.  (And name isn't always the same; I'm just looking to give a starting value.)

Comment: The thing is I don't think this can be achieved in any other way but with a trigger. Or perhaps with something as convoluted as: `INSERT INTO names (name) VALUE (CONCAT('I am number ', SELECT auto_increment FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = DATABASE() AND table_name = 'name'));` ;)

Comment: `name` won't be always the same, but is it deterministic? The view definition could also be somthing like `CREATE VIEW names_v AS SELECT id, someCustomFunction(id) AS name FROM names;`

Comment: :) Thanks, YaK - better word. No, name isn't always deterministic (or formulaic).  I'm just giving a default value.

Answer (score 0):

I've also recently been facing this problem and although it might not be the best solution, what I did could be a viable alternative for your case. In my case it was sufficient. You could use a AFTER INSERT trigger to update the field with the value refering to the pseudo-variable NEW. This will probably give you a bit more flexibility.
I needed to fill a field with a string that was computed using the value from the auto increment column.
The trigger reads the NEW pseudo-variable, computes the necessary values and executes the UPDATE.
It still does require two high level write-acesses to the database, but all are done consecutively and without the need for further interaction with the client application (effectively, one single insert statement being sent from the client application, being followed by the implicit update).